# How do you have a mobile view for a Kentico CMS product?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, kentico

I need to update the e-commerce product in Desktop version to view full screen in the mobile website.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do doesn't concern the Kentico CMS. So no, there isn't an option for it.

What you want to do is modify the *CSS* of the product's view using a **media query**. [(See this other stackoverflow question for more detail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469875/how-to-code-css-media-queries-targeting-all-mobile-devices-and-tablets)

Something like:

```
@media(max-width: 400px) { //Note 400px is irrelevant, you want to specify what width your CSS changes.
    .myProductClass {
        width: 100%; //Or whatever else you need to do for __only__ mobile devices.
    }
}
```