# Bootstrap 2.3 grid manipulation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap website that I want customized based on the user's device.

Here's an image to clearly show you how I want it to happen.[image]

So in the original design (desktop), I used four span3 to produce that layout. Is it possible to turn it into three column and two column for tablet and mobile, respectively? Or do I have to use different mark-ups for different devices? Thanks!

Comment: It is possible in Bootstrap 3. Is there a reason why you can't upgrade? If you not able you will need to play with media queries.

Comment: I can't since I'm using a framework that uses Bootstrap 2.3.
If that's the case, perhaps using media queries would be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 does most of this for you, Otherwise liljoshu has written a good answer for it here:

[How to code CSS media queries targeting ALL mobile devices and tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469875/how-to-code-css-media-queries-targeting-all-mobile-devices-and-tablets)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. Please note that I am using Bootstrap 2.3. What happens is when the window is resized to mobile, the 4 column turns to 1. Perhaps I can modify its behavior like when it's on tablet, make it 3 columns, when it's on phone, it should be 2 columns.

Comment: Check out the link i attached to the answer, liljoshu has posted a explanation of doing this using media tags in css. It is essentially how bootstrap 3 does it as well