# I wanna show diffrent images as per the device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use two diffrent image in my project as backgrouund because both have diffrent designs and desktop image looking odd in mobile devices.so is it possible to show BG image as per mobile device.Here is the demo which i create https://codeslide.in/contact.

am using codeigniter framework.Below is code as i use two images in css but not working.

```js
// Step 3 - Instilize the plugin by #id selector
VANTA.BIRDS({
  el: "body",
  colorMode: "varianceGradient",
  wingSpan: 23.00,
  speedLimit: 8.00,
  separation: 60.00,
  alignment: 35.00,
  cohesion: 24.00,
  backgroundAlpha: 0.36,
 }})
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.sclance.com/backgrounds/svg-background-image/svg-background-image_2162863.jpg");
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527335480088-278dbeec0ad5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80");
  }
}
}
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/100/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.vantajs.com/dist/vanta.birds.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
```

Comment: body is apply to the tag <body> to target <div class="body"> you have to use .body{}

Comment: Are you sure that your phone's screen is only 600 pixels wide? some phones have bigger screens, and people can rotate the phone to get even more width. As far as I know there is no way to reliably detect with pure css that it's a phone.

Comment: can you show it by create a new snippet

Comment: @potato Every user has their own screen size.I use this method from here.https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_bg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use media query for this i have write some code for you, you can use this, if i am right..

```css
body {
 background-image: url("http://www.sclance.com/backgrounds/svg-background-image/svg-background-image_2162863.jpg");
}


/** For Mobile Device landscape and portrait view **/

@media (max-width:767px){
body {
 background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527335480088-278dbeec0ad5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80");
}

}

/** For I pad portrait view**/

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
body {
 background-image: url("https://i0.wp.com/www.wwhf.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bokeh-cover-bg.jpg?ssl=1");
}

}

/** For I pad landscape view**/

@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1024px) {
body {
 background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSI3Elr_JO2Y8pkoTb0QhVw91qcUOwhWrNlPX3icMrLqylfMk8u");
}

}
```

```html
<body>
some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text

</body>
```

Comment: @Codeslide Creation if is this helpful for you please do up-vote is this helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Using the `@media` rule is unreliable because some phones have wider screens, and people can rotate their screen to make it even wider.

You can use javascript to add a class to the `body` element if it detects the `window.orientation` property (which tells you how the phone's screen is rotated)

```
if (window.orientation !== undefined) {
  document.body.classList.add("mobile");
}
```

(according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025632/how-to-detect-only-with-css-mobile-screens/#55645902))

### Full example code

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         if (window.orientation !== undefined) {
            document.body.classList.add("mobile");
         }
      </script>
      <style>
         body{
            background-color: green;
         }
         body.mobile{
            background-color: blue;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      Body should have different background color depending on the device.
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not Working i add above lines `<style>
#wrapper {
  background-image: url("http://www.sclance.com/backgrounds/svg-background-image/svg-background-image_2162863.jpg");
}
if (window.orientation !== undefined) {
  document.body.classList.add("mobile");
}
 
  body {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527335480088-278dbeec0ad5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80");
  }
}
}
}
</style>`

Comment: It is `javascript` code, not `css` code, it needs to be in a `<script>` tag outside the `<style>` tag. All it does is add a class to the `body` element. Then you can write in your `css` code how you want to style things that are/in `body.mobile`.

Comment: i added this code `if (window.orientation !== undefined) {
  document.body.classList.add("mobile");
}` above of vanta.birds but the problem is same.

Comment: here is the paste https://pasteshr.com/6fXavyEKEL changes i made but still not working.

Comment: there seems to be a part in the code that I wasn't aware of, the `#wrapper` is probably covering the `body` background. You need to either use an element as the background or use the body's background property, they are not interchangeable.