# Pointer-events only disabled on desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries, pointer-events

Via CSS I disabled the pointer-events. However, on mobile I want to activate it.

My attempt:

```
.videoContainer {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .videoContainer {
        pointer-events: all;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work for me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events: `pointer-events: all; /* SVG only */` - so don’t use `all`, use `auto`.

Comment: Some good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12469875/1207195