# Media query for mobile devices works on an emulated mobile device, but not on my phone

Tags: html, css, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, media-queries

I've got this media query that checks if the device is mobile.

```css
@media only screen and (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
  body {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: purple; /*added this for debugging */
  }
  
  #navbar {
    justify-content: center;  
  }
  
  #nav-left {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #nav-right {
    font-size: 0.75em;
  }
  
  #projects {
    grid-template-columns: 400px 400px;
    grid-template-rows: 400px 400px /*400px 400px*/;
  }
  
  .project-wrapper {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .project-tile:hover .project-wrapper {
    animation-name: delay_link;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
  }
  
  @keyframes delay_link {
    90% {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    100% {
      pointer-events: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

It fires when I emulate a mobile device in Chrome DevTools. Notice the text turning purple.

[image: The website emulated on a virtual mobile device in Chrome DevTools]

However, if I open the page on my phone it won't work. How comes that the emulated device is different from the actual device?

[image: The website opened on Chrome for Android]

My full code: https://codepen.io/julian-sz/pen/vYxOLQx?editors=1101

My full code (debug view): https://cdpn.io/julian-sz/debug/vYxOLQx/dXkqBaPZYZPM

My Chrome version: 91.0.4472.77 (Official build) (64-Bit) (cohort: 91_Win_77)

My Chrome version on Android (Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite): 90.0.4430.210

Comment: how should that check if you sue a mobile device or not? The standard still is to check by screen-size. Then it comes down to the diffrence between hardware pixels and css-pixels. A reason why that still works flawlessly even up today.

Comment: I have taken the concept from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42835826/14207819)

Comment: @tacoshy I don't understand why that tells you whether you are on a touch device or not (which is sort of what hover does) - if I have a small viewport on my laptop I don't see the tests you mention telling me correctly that it isn't actually a mobile.

Comment: Which phone and browser are you using?

Comment: no lap top has a width of smaller then 480px in portrait-mode. No smartphone a width larger then 480px in portrait-mode.

Comment: @AHaworth I've included my phone and browser in my question.

Comment: @tacoshy, I guess it depends on what you are really trying to find out - whether the device is touchscreen only, whether it is narrow - neither say whether it's mobile or a phone (e.g. iPads etc or narrow window on a laptop etc).

Answer (score 0):

Have you added meta viewport into head?

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Comment: The media query fires on my phone when I add this tag, but now the sizes of all elements have been changed. (only on a mobile device - the page looks normal on my PC)