# Tailwind add class depending on the existence of a body class

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm currently migrating from css modules to tailwind and we have some helper classes on the body to identify the used device:

```
<body class="body-app body-ios">
```

By using a mixin, we were previously able to easily add custom styles depending on the device (mobile, desktop or app (if the site is displayed in our app as a webview)), the used browser, or if it support touch. Example:

```
@mixin ios {
    :global(.body--ios) & {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin app {
    :global(.body--app) & {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to have something similar in tailwind. Ideally something similar to the pseudo-selectors. Something like

```
ios:text-md
```

Is it even possible or what would be the next best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was fairly simple. I made use of the tailwind plugin api to write my own custom selector like this:

`tailwind.config.js`

```
plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
        addVariant('app', 'body.body--app &');
        addVariant('mobile', 'body.body--mobile &');
        addVariant('desktop', 'body.body--desktop &');
        addVariant('ios', 'body.body--iOS &');
        addVariant('windows', 'body.body--Windows &');
    }),
],
```

With those plugins in place I can use them like this: `app:p-10` which only gets applied if the body element has the `body--app` class

Answer (score 0):

Use tailwind's screen modifiers that apply the style based on the screen size: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens

In tailwind.config.js you can define your mobile specification like:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'mobile': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

    }
  }
}
```

You can add additional screen modifiers based on your needs, we are at an age where the lines are getting blurry between what's considered a mobile device or not, so its best to design your application based on screen sizes instead.

Comment: I specifically don't want that. We have different layouts depending on the used device. Even if you change your browser size on your desktop pc, we don't want to style it differently.
Another example is a selector for `body--ios` (webkit browser edge cases) or `body--app` (the website is displayed in a webview in our app and needs slighty different styling). So this solution is not sufficient

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no way to specifically determine if something is a mobile device using pure tailwind but this workaround could help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42835826/17985195](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42835826/17985195)

Comment: But we know it because the body has the class since we set it ourself on the body. In normal css I can alreay write the selector `body.--body-app .myElement { color: red }` which would make the text for the class myElement red if I'm using the website via the app. I want this selector usable in tailwaind ideally with the usual pseudo selector syntax`sm:text-md`but now like `app:text-md`